# Tabbar current index height change in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

1. How to change the current index tabbar.
2. I have three tabbar with images when I click index 0 the height will
   change to big like focus.
3. I have tried several ways but it didn't work.
4. when I select it will work only one index

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> void main() {
>   runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
> }
>
> class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
>   MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
> }
>
> class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>         home: DefaultTabController(
>       length: 3,
>       child: Scaffold(
>           appBar: AppBar(
>             backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
>             toolbarHeight: 100,
>             bottom: TabBar(
>                 indicator: BoxDecoration(
>                     border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.deepOrange),
>                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
>                     color: Colors.transparent),
>                 tabs: [
>                   Card(
>                     child: Image(
>                       image: AssetImage("assets/box.png"),
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                   Card(
>                     child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/box.png")),
>                   ),
>                   Card(
>                     child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/box.png")),
>                   ),
>                 ]),
>           ),
>           body: TabBarView(
>             children: [
>               AmazonBox(),
>               AmazonGift(),
>               AmazonSave(),
>             ],
>           )),
>     ));
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the active tab icon a bigger size than the other icons, you have to create your own TabController first. Then add a listener to that TabController to update your Widget with setState() every time the tab index changes. Compare the tab icon index with the current index of the TabController to decide whether to display a big or small tab icon.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this)
    ..animation?.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            toolbarHeight: 100,
            bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.transparent),
                tabs: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: _tabController.index == 0 ? 100 : 50,
                    height: _tabController.index == 0 ? 100 : 50,
                    child: const Image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/box.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: _tabController.index == 1 ? 100 : 50,
                    height: _tabController.index == 1 ? 100 : 50,
                    child: const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/box.png")),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: _tabController.index == 2 ? 100 : 50,
                    height: _tabController.index == 2 ? 100 : 50,
                    child: const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/box.png")),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: const [
              AmazonBox(),
              AmazonGift(),
              AmazonSave(),
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```